# unclear c code: double underscore in c macro

Tags: c, assembly, macros

I have to interpret some c-code as a kind of homework and I don't really understand this macro:

```
#define rdtscll(val)__asm__ __volatile__("rdtsc":"=A"(val))
```

I know it's some kind of static function named `rdtscll` which receives one parameter `val`. But what about the rest?

- What are `__asm__` and `__volatile__` and why those underscores?
- are those 2 different constants separated by a space?

Comment: did you try searching for any info? check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14950614/2173917)

Comment: That's two unrelated questions. Removing the second one.

Comment: This is not C, but an extension to integrate assembler. Are you sure that you are supposed to understand this part of the example that your teacher gave to you?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26456510/what-does-asm-volatile-do-in-c

Comment: @Deduplicator modified the question itself as the second part is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case `__asm__` and `__volatile__` are compiler extensions for embedding assembly statements into a C file. The two leading underscores are to prevent clashes with identifiers in user code, and the trailing are pure choice. `__volatile__` is just an "anti-optimization" directive.

`rdtsc` is an x86 instruction for reading the Time-Stamp Counter, a very high-speed counter based on clock cycles. `"=A"` is part of the GCC inline assembly syntax - there are plenty of references explaining more about it.